# Is there any SQL Server database available for practice which contains more then 1 million rows in each table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, bigdata

Is there any SQL Server database available for practice which contains more then 1 million rows in each table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use stackoverflow database itself:

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/10/how-to-download-the-stack-overflow-database-via-bittorrent/

I'm not sure if all tables have over 1 mln rows but as I remember db is big and certainly good for performance excersises.